# Javascript: insert new member of array after each nth member

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I need to insert a new member into Javascript array after each nth member.

If I try iterating over array and inserting new members with `array.splice()`, it doesn't work because any type of iterating loop relies on array length, which changes on every iteration. For example, i have array like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and want to make it like:

```
[1, 2, 'insert this', 3, 4, 'insert this', 5, 6, 'insert this', 7, 8, 'insert this', 9, 10, 'insert this']
```

If I try code below, I end up with empty array:

```
var dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var itemIndex = 2; itemIndex < dataRow.length; itemIndex += 2) {
    dataRow.splice(itemIndex, 0, 'insert this');
}
```

This question is not a duplicate of questions where people just wanted to get member of array or to insert it at one particular position. Problem is, how to do it at every nth position.

Comment: Instead of mutating the the actual array, you can generate a new one from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your code to this. Add 3 to itemIndex to account for 1 insertion as well.

```js
var dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var itemIndex = 2; itemIndex < dataRow.length; itemIndex += 3) {
    
    dataRow.splice(itemIndex, 0, 'insert this');
}

console.log(dataRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the end and splice the extra item.

```js
var dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var itemIndex = Math.floor(dataRow.length / 2) * 2; itemIndex > 0; itemIndex -= 2) {
    dataRow.splice(itemIndex, 0, 'insert this');
}

console.log(dataRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var length = dataRow.length;
for (var i = 1; i <= length / 2; i++) {
    dataRow.splice(i * 3 - 1, 0, 'insert this');
}
console.log(dataRow);
```

Hope this works!